# 7z commandline: test archive and only show failures?

Tags: linux, command-line, unix, 7-zip, esxi

What is the easiest way to get only the failures from `7z` when testing an archive for integrity?

Looking at the command-line options, there seems to be no `verbose` or `non-verbose` option (i.e. there seems to be no way to log more/less information).

Any smart unix shell tricks I can use (preferably tricks that also work on ESXi with the p7zip x86 binaries; I think ESXi uses the [ash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almquist_shell) shell) to only list failed archives and failed content in archives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm interpreting your question as: *I want to know only if the archive passed the integrity check or not.*

```
if 7za t <archive> 2>&1 > /dev/null; then echo passed; else echo failed; fi
```

This redirects all output from the command to */dev/null* and only checks the exit status. 7za will return 0 if the archive is valid, and non-zero on any failures.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Thinking back this almost what I had in mind. In the future I want to figure out how to get more output on the failures, but this will do for now.

Comment: Thanks again: this saved my day after running for almost a day (: `for filename in *.7z; do if 7za t $filename 2>&1 > /dev/null; then echo $filename passed; else echo $filename failed; fi; done`